# Why is my texture distorted on my spiral staircaise?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, shaders, uv-image-editor

Why is my texture distorted on my spiral staircaise ?
I make "follow active quads", try every options of texture coordinates.

Thanks ! [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share your file?

Comment: Thanks !  i add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A face is made of 2 triangles, if you unwrap with the *Follow Active Quads* option, the UV faces will be deformed compared to the original faces, and it will stretch slightly these 2 inner triangles, which will create this distortion in the face (the green line shows the separation between the 2 triangles):

[image]

To fix that, subdivide your mesh enough (here, see the loopcuts I've created in only one direction) so that the inner triangulations (inside each new face) become unnoticeable:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! ça m'avait complétement échappé !

Comment: and, how can i do for having my texture straight and not curved ?

Comment: you can't with this method, as your stairs are curved, you need another way